# Erro para calcular a media de uma coluna numérica no R

Tags: r

Não estou conseguindo calcular a media de uma coluna mesmo ela sendo numérica.

quando coloco summary aparece: [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM5YF.png)

ja quando coloco:

```
baseNIT |> mean(Totalinf, na.rm = T )
```

---

```
> baseNIT |> mean(Totalinf, na.rm = T )
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(baseNIT, Totalinf, na.rm = T) :
  argumento não é numérico nem lógico: retornando NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Como o data frame `baseNIT` não foi fornecido, utilizarei o data frame `iris`, já presente em qualquer instalação do R, para responder esta pergunta, sem perda de generalidade.

Considerando a sintaxe `x |> f(y)`, em que `x` é um expressão que retorna algum resultado e `f()` é alguma expressão do R, o comando `|>` significa fazer `f(x, y)`. Portanto,

```r
iris |> 
  mean(Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)
```

quer dizer

```r
mean(iris, Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)
```

o que não é a maneira correta de calcular a média de uma coluna de um data frame. Isto foi alterado na versão 3.0.0, na qual, segundo as notícias do seu lançamento,

> `mean()` for data frames and `sd()` for data frames and matrices are defunct.

Neste caso, o ideal seria primeiro selecionar a coluna desejada e, sem seguida, calcular a sua média. Sem utilizar nenhum pacote extra, uma forma de fazer isso é

```r
iris[, "Petal.Length"] |> 
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 3.758
```

Caso prefira usar o `dplyr`, uma maneira de obter este resultado é

```r
library(dplyr)

iris |> 
  summarise(media = mean(Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE))
#>   media
#> 1 3.758
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Portanto, para o conjunto de dados utilizado pelo OP, as sintaxes acima se tornam

```r
baseNIT[, "Totalinf"] |> 
  mean(na.rm = T )
```

e

```r
baseNIT |> 
  summarise(media = mean(Totalinf, na.rm = TRUE))
```

respectivamente.